# Mock function call inside other function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

How to mock a function call inside another function in JavaScript?

Code example:

returnNumber.js

```
export default function returnNumber() {
  return 5;
}
```

myFunction.js

```
import returnNumber from "./returnNumber";

export default function myFunction(input) {
  return input + returnNumber();
}
```

I would like to test it by doing something like this, but none if the code examples I saw seem to be working in my case

myFunction.test.js

```
import myFunction from "./myFunction";

test("myFunction should equal 6", async () => {
  returnNumber = () => {
    return 1
  }

  expect(myFunction(5)).toEqual(6);
});
```

Considering the example above; can I test myFunction while overriding returnNumber's return value without changing the code of returnNumber.js / myFunction.js?

Answer (score -1):

i think you usually use jest to mock the return value of the function like so:

```
import myFunctionService from './myFunctionService';

test('myFunction', async () => {
jest.spyOn(myFunctionService, 'returnNumber').mockReturnValue(1);
const result = myFunction(5);

expect(result).toBe(6);
}
```

class should be something like this:

```
export default class myFunctionService {
    constructor() {}
    
    myFunction(input) {
      return input + returnNumber();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already tried a lot of things with Jest but never managed to get the mocking thing to work.

Your answer unfortunately returns 'Cannot spy the undefined property because it is not a function'.

Comment: are you importing the function in your jest test?

Comment: once you import it you should be able to mock the return value with jest. maybe it helps to  write a class containing the returnNumber function and then spyOn the class inside the test like so, let me edit answer